# Unable to execute create stored procedure using Entity Framework 6 with npgsql in postgresql code first

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations, npgsql

I am not able to create a stored procedure in npgsql using ASP.NET MVC 5.

My migration code is:

```
CreateStoredProcedure("dbo.CustomerDetails_Insert",
                p => new
                {
                    p_chrv_ah_name = p.String(maxLength: 150),
                    p_chrv_ah_desig = p.String(maxLength: 50),
                    p_chrv_org_name = p.String(maxLength: 150),
                    p_chrv_org_phone = p.String(maxLength: 50),
                    p_chrv_org_email = p.String(maxLength: 150),
                    p_chrv_org_logo = p.String(maxLength: 150),
                    p_chrv_org_logo_path = p.String(maxLength: 255),
                    p_chrv_pwd = p.String(maxLength: 12),
                    p_tms_agreement_on = p.String(maxLength: 150),
                    p_chrv_agree_scan_copy = p.String(maxLength: 150),
                    p_chrv_agree_scan_copy_path = p.String(maxLength: 150),
                    p_chrv_ip_address = p.String(maxLength: 150)
                },
                body:
                @"  DECLARE id character varying;
                    id= select 'cust' || EXTRACT (month from current_date)|| to_char(current_date,'yy')|| (select LPAD(CAST((select coalesce(max(int_slno),0)+1 from dbo.customer_details) as character varying),2,'0'))
                    INSERT INTO dbo.customer_details(chrv_cust_id,chrv_ah_name,chrv_ah_desig,chrv_org_name,chrv_org_phone,chrv_org_email,chrv_org_logo,chrv_org_logo_path,int_created_by,chrv_ip_address,chrv_pwd,tms_agreement_on,chrv_agree_scan_copy,chrv_agree_scan_copy_path)
                    VALUES(id,p_chrv_ah_name,p_chrv_ah_desig,p_chrv_org_name,p_chrv_org_phone,p_chrv_org_email,p_chrv_org_logo,p_chrv_org_logo_path,0,p_chrv_ip_address,p_chrv_pwd,p_tms_agreement_on,p_chrv_agree_scan_copy,p_chrv_agree_scan_copy_path);
                    "
                );
```

but I get this error

> Unhandled MigrationOperation CreateProcedureOperation in NpgsqlMigrationSqlGenerator

Does someone have the solution for this? If so, please post.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is currently not supported by the provider. You can open an issue to request this at https://github.com/npgsql/EntityFramework6.Npgsql, although we don't have much time to invest in it at the moment...